# Regex con números, sin incluir texto

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero hacer un regex que recoja el número decimal, pero que no recoja cuando esta junto a un texto.

```
Ejemplo:

    123 -----> Sí
    12.34 ---> Sí
    as12 ----> No
    op12as --> No
    opa12.1 -> No
```

De momento tengo mi regex así `/^((\d+\.\d+|\d)+)/g`, y he estado intentado poner negadores, pero no me funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje de programación estás usando?

Comment: Estoy usando javascript

Comment: No hace falta complicarse tanto, `^\d+\.?\d*$` cumple exactamente lo que pides. Puedes verlo funcionando en [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0USc5J/1)

Comment: @Benito-B No es lo que busco, porque el texto puede empezar con espacios

Comment: @ABC Menos mal que esto es STACKOVERFLOW y no ADIVINAFLOW. Si quieres que te ayudemos de manera concisa, expón lo que necesitas de manera concisa. No quiero estar editando el patrón 50 veces si cada vez vas añadiendo más requisitos :) Pon al menos *TODOS* los valores que necesitas que sean válidos y los que no, que si no estamos aquí todos perdiendo el tiempo para no responder correctamente. De todas maneras, el patrón que te he dado debería ser sencillo de editar para que encaje con lo que pides.

Comment: ¿Con un grupo opcional? `/^ +?(\d+(?:.\d+)?)$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esta expresión regular...

```
 /^[\d]([\d\.]+)\s/gm
```

puedes excluir si tiene un caracter diferente a digito al principio (letras) y que finalice un caracter espacio, adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

en vez de usar |, se pueden usar ? y * para indicar que esas partes de la expresion regular no son obligatorias. ? nos indica 0 o 1 apariciones y * nos indica 0 o más apariciones

```js
const regex = /^\s*\d+\.?\d*$/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('^\\d+\\.?\\d*$', 'gm')

const str = `123
 -----> Sí
          123
 -----> Sí
12.34
 ---> Sí
as12
 ----> No
op12as
 --> No
opa12.1
 -> No`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Veo que ambos hemos ido al mismo patrón :) Otra opción para los opcionales es usar `{0,1}` que indica que debe aparecer entre 0 y 1 veces. Poco útil en este caso, pero siempre está bien que lo sepan para cuando necesitan que algo aparezca entre n y m veces

Answer (score 0):

#### Número separado del texto

Te presento a **`\b`**. Es un límite de palabra, y no coincide con un caracter sino con una **posición**: una posición entre un caracter de texto (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) que no tiene al lado a otro caracter de texto.

`\b` coincide:

- entre el inicio del texto y un caracter de texto
- entre un caracter que no es de texto seguido por otro que sí
- entre un caracter de texto seguido de otro que no
- entre un caracter de texto y el final del texto

Si rodeamos al patrón para un número de `\b`s te podés asegurar de que no tenga caracteres alfabéticos ni `_` alrededor:

```
/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/g
```

Tiene a favor que vas a poder hacer que coincida con algo como `(23+12.3)`, pero la contra de que con `ab67.8` coincidiría con `8` porque formalmente no está rodeado de caracteres de palabra.

#### Pero también con vocales acentuadas, ü, ñ y puntos

que no están incluidos en `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`... Para eso se nos complica apenas un poco porque tenemos que usar un lookbehind negativo `(?<!` `)`, que comprueba que no esté precedido por un patrón; y un lookahead negativo `(?!` `)`,  que verifica que no esté seguido de un patrón.

```
/(?<![\wáéíóúüñ.])\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![\wáéíóúüñ.])/ig
```